# Gerrit uses wrong collation

Tags: mysql, sql, gerrit

I'm trying to authenticate Gerrit users using ldap against Active Directory.
I get the following error.

> ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.cache.PopulatingCache : Cannot lookup CN%3DORG+%C3%96resund+ALL%2COU%3DOrganisation%2COU%3DGroups%2COU%3DOther%2C
>   DC%3Dcompany%2CDC%3Dcom in "groups_byext"
>   net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Could not fetch object for cache entry with key "CN%3DORG+%C3%96resund+ALL%2COU%3DOrganisation%2COU%3DGroups%2COU%3DOther%2CDC%3Dcompany%2CDC%
>   3Dcom".
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

I am not very experienced in mysql or Active Directory, so I'm pretty much clueless on this issue.

Any suggestions of what the problem might be?

Comment: I should add that I have successfully authenticated against an OpenLDAP server. (Experimental setup only.)

Answer (score 0):

That is a MySQL error, not an LDAP error.  Sounds like you're getting a list of groups, but it can't check against its local group permission table because the database connection is using the wrong encoding.

[This thread suggests a solution](http://groups.google.com/group/repo-discuss/browse_thread/thread/e1d1d0a5072651) in the JDBC connection string in gerrit.conf:

```
url = jdbc:mysql://foo/reviewdb?user=x&password=y&useUnicode=false&characterEncoding=latin1
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that. Still the same error. The reason why I tagged the question with ldap is that the error stems from the authentication over LDAP.